# Is there a way to use Hibernate's AUTO GenerationType with a byte?

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jpa, spring-boot

I have a MySQL table with a TINYINT(3) as the primary key.  From what I understand (and what passes the hibernate 'validate' setting), the byte type maps to TINYINT.  Everything compiles fine and will retrieve all the data.  However, when I go to create a new entry, I get this error:

```
org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException: unrecognized id type : byte -> java.lang.Byte; nested exception is org.hibernate.id.IdentifierGenerationException: unrecognized id type : byte -> java.lang.Byte] with root cause
```

I am using the annotation `@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)` on the `@Id` field.  Is there any way to make this work?

Thanks.

Here is the entire class:

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Objects;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name="unittypes",schema="utilities")
public class UnitType implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private byte unitTypeID;
    private String unitTypeName;

    public UnitType() {}

    public UnitType(String unitTypeName) {
        this.unitTypeName = unitTypeName;
    }

    @Id
    @Column(name="pk_unittypeid")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    public byte getUnitTypeID() {
        return unitTypeID;
    }

    public void setUnitTypeID(byte unitTypeID) {
        this.unitTypeID = unitTypeID;
    }

    @Column(name="unittypename", unique=true, nullable=false)
    public String getUnitTypeName() {
        return unitTypeName;
    }

    public void setUnitTypeName(String unitTypeName) {
        this.unitTypeName = unitTypeName;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int hash = 7;
        hash = 41 * hash + Objects.hashCode(this.unitTypeName);
        return hash;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj) {
            return true;
        }
        if (obj == null) {
            return false;
        }
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass()) {
            return false;
        }
        final UnitType other = (UnitType) obj;
        if (!Objects.equals(this.unitTypeName, other.unitTypeName)) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: could you show your Java class?